# Auto run a method in a webservice on startup

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

I want to create a web-service that run a specific method on startup.
this is the service's interface:

```
namespace MyClass
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string getData();

    }
}
```

and on the service itself i want a specific method (not one of those) to run when the service loads (or deployed to IIS). is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be clear what really happens when a WCF service is hosting in IIS.

- IIS provides a **service host** that loads on demand
- when a request comes in, IIS instantiates the service host, which in turns instantiates an instance of your service class, passes it the parameters from the request, and then executes the appropriate method on the service class

As such, there is no point in time when the "service loads" and then just lingers around in memory. The "service" isn't just loaded when IIS starts up and then would be "present and ready" at all times...

So where do you want to plug in??

- when the **service host** loads in IIS? In that case, you'd have to create your own custom service host and register it with IIS so that IIS would use your custom host instead of the WCF default service host
- when the actual service class is instantiated to handle the request? THen put your logic into the constructor of your service class - it will be executed each time a service class is instantiated to handle a request

Comment: What if the service host run in a [managed windows service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx)? How can I execute an auto run with it?

Comment: @JohnIsaiahCarmona: as I said - there is no real "autorun" functionality at all. Put any code that needs to be run just before the service call is handled into the service class' constructor if you're using the "per-call" activation model - that code will be run when the service class is instantiated just before it can handle the request

Comment: I post [my question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937810/wcf-run-service-constructor-once-with-an-instancecontextmode-of-persession) for further details. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Though this might not be exactly what you want, you could use the class's constructor, perhaps:

```
public class Service : IService
{
    public Service()
    {
        //code here will execute when an instance 
        //of this service class is instantiated
    }

    string getData() { ... }
}
```

It would be more clear if you could inform us of the method you wish to call, and any surrounding information about it, so that you don't get ill-advice. Specifics are nice.

Comment: I want to know what is the address when i load and store it somewhere without a special outside hoster.  something like "this.getAddress"

Comment: Then this should suffice, just get the address and store it somewhere (temporarily for access throughout the lifetime of the instance); you might want to consider a more long term solution, but for addresses I would go for the _here & now_ option, rather than caching something that _might_ just change. Also, I would add relevant information to your original question so that others have the benefit of reading it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Here's where I put some code in order to get (and cache) data on the webservice start (in VB). You do need to trigger the service by navigating to any valid or invalid

```
Public Module WebApiConfig
    Public Sub Register(ByVal config As HttpConfiguration)
        'Run this method on startup to cache the addresses
        Address.GetAll()

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name:="DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional}
        )
    End Sub
End Module
```